# Trading strategy P&L for holding period - solve rolling_apply bottleneck

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

I am calculating a `DataFrame` of profit/loss amounts for every row in a `DataFrame` containing price data.

The logic is as follows:

- We buy/sell the asset at the current time period.
- We hold the asset for `holding_period`.
- If, during the holding period, the price exceeds `take_profit`, exit at that price for a profit.
- If, during the holding period, the price exceeds `stop_loss`, exit at that price for a loss.
- The first `take_profit` or `stop_loss` level seen determines whether we exit at a profit or loss.
- If neither the take profit or stop loss are reached, exit at the last price in the holding period.

The way I have implemented this is to use [`pandas.rolling_apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html), which *applies* a provided function onto a rolling window of each series in the `DataFrame`.

Given `rolling_apply` calls a function for every row and column combination in the `DataFrame`, it is a serious bottleneck.

I am wondering if there are better ways to achieve this using other pandas/numpy functionality?

This is the current implementation:

```
def potential_pnl(prices, side, periods, take_profit=np.nan, stop_loss=np.nan):

    # set sign depending on direction of price movement required by BUY/SELL
    if side == Side.SELL:
        take_profit *= -1
    else:
        stop_loss *= -1

    def period_potential_pnl(window):
        # enter at the first price, rest of the window are possible exit prices
        entry_price = window[0]
        exit_prices = window[1:]

        take_profit_price = entry_price + take_profit
        stop_loss_price   = entry_price + stop_loss

        # calculate array of bools showing where take_profit/stop_loss is reached
        if side == Side.BUY:
            filtered = exit_prices[ (exit_prices >= take_profit_price) |
                                    (exit_prices <= stop_loss_price) ]
        else:
            filtered = exit_prices[ (exit_prices <= take_profit_price) |
                                    (exit_prices >= stop_loss_price) ]

        # if neither take_profit/stop_loss is reached, exit at the last price
        # otherwise exit at the first price which exceeds take_profit/stop_loss
        if len(filtered) == 0:
            exit_price = exit_prices[-1]
        else:
            exit_price = filtered[0]

        exit_pnl = exit_price - entry_price
        if side == Side.SELL:
            exit_pnl *= -1
        return exit_pnl

    # apply `period_potential_pnl` onto the dataframe
    pnl = pd.rolling_apply(prices, periods + 1, period_potential_pnl)

    # shift back by periods so the exit pnl is lined up with the entry price
    pnl = pnl.shift(-periods)[:-periods]
    return pnl
```

**Things I have tried:**

I initially used [`pandas.rolling_max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html) and [`pandas.rolling_min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_min.html) to determine whether the `take_profit` or `stop_loss` was reached.

The problem I had with this approach was two-fold:

- You can't use the max as the exit price for `take_profit`, because the `take_profit` could very well have been reached at a lower price; it is impossible to know in realtime what the max of the holding period will be.
- You can't determine which of the `take_profit` or `stop_loss` is reached first.

**Question:**

Is there a more efficient way to calculate the P&L at each period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to go about this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
```

Sample data:

```
prices = DataReader('IBM', 'yahoo', datetime(2015, 1, 1), datetime.today().utcnow())['Open'].resample('D').fillna(method='ffill')
prices.head()

Date
2015-01-02    161.309998
2015-01-03    161.309998
2015-01-04    161.309998
2015-01-05    161.270004
2015-01-06    159.669998
Freq: D, Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

function to calculate `pnl` - get the first date where take_profit, cut_loss or period_end occurs, and calculate P&L using the corresponding exit price (reverse `profit_goal` and `cut_loss` for a `sell` strategy:

```
def get_pnl(prices, start_date, holding_period=90, profit_goal=0.10, cut_loss=.10):
    end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=holding_period)
    data = prices[start_date: end_date]

    start_price = data.iloc[0]
    take_profit = start_price * (1 + profit_goal)
    cut_loss = start_price * (1 - cut_loss)
    exit_date = end_date

    if (data > take_profit).any():
        exit_date = data[data > take_profit].index[0]
    if (data[:exit_date] < cut_loss).any():
        exit_date = data[data < cut_loss].index[0]

    exit_price = data.loc[exit_date]
    print('Entered on {0} at: {1:.2f}, exited on {2} at {3:.2f} for {4:.2f}%'.format(start_date.strftime('%Y-%b-%d'), start_price, exit_date.strftime('%Y-%b-%d'), exit_price, (exit_price/start_price-1)*100))
```

and test run:

```
for start_date in [datetime(2015, 1, 1) + relativedelta(months=i) for i in range(12)]:
    get_pnl(prices, start_date)
```

to get:

```
Entered on 2015-Jan-01 at 161.31, exited on 2015-Apr-01 at 160.23 for -0.67%
Entered on 2015-Feb-01 at 153.91, exited on 2015-Apr-24 at 170.23 for 10.60%
Entered on 2015-Mar-01 at 160.87, exited on 2015-May-30 at 171.35 for 6.51%
Entered on 2015-Apr-01 at 160.23, exited on 2015-Jun-30 at 163.99 for 2.35%
Entered on 2015-May-01 at 173.20, exited on 2015-Jul-30 at 160.50 for -7.33%
Entered on 2015-Jun-01 at 170.21, exited on 2015-Aug-20 at 152.74 for -10.26%
Entered on 2015-Jul-01 at 163.97, exited on 2015-Aug-24 at 143.47 for -12.50%
Entered on 2015-Aug-01 at 161.40, exited on 2015-Aug-24 at 143.47 for -11.11%
Entered on 2015-Sep-01 at 144.91, exited on 2015-Nov-30 at 138.61 for -4.35%
Entered on 2015-Oct-01 at 145.31, exited on 2015-Dec-30 at 139.58 for -3.94%
Entered on 2015-Nov-01 at 140.44, exited on 2016-Jan-20 at 118.46 for -15.65%
Entered on 2015-Dec-01 at 139.58, exited on 2016-Jan-20 at 118.46 for -15.13%
```